# Why do I get "panicked at 'not currently running on the Tokio runtime'" when using block_on from the futures crate?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I'm using the example code on elastic search's blog post about their new crate and I'm unable to get it working as intended. The thread panics with `thread 'main' panicked at 'not currently running on the Tokio runtime.'`.

What is the Tokio runtime, how do I configure it and why must I?

```
use futures::executor::block_on;

async elastic_search_example() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let index_response = client
        .index(IndexParts::IndexId("tweets", "1"))
        .body(json!({
            "user": "kimchy",
            "post_date": "2009-11-15T00:00:00Z",
            "message": "Trying out Elasticsearch, so far so good?"
        }))
        .refresh(Refresh::WaitFor)
        .send()
        .await?;
    if !index_response.status_code().is_success() {
        panic!("indexing document failed")
    }
    let index_response = client
        .index(IndexParts::IndexId("tweets", "2"))
        .body(json!({
            "user": "forloop",
            "post_date": "2020-01-08T00:00:00Z",
            "message": "Indexing with the rust client, yeah!"
        }))
        .refresh(Refresh::WaitFor)
        .send()
        .await?;
    if !index_response.status_code().is_success() {
        panic!("indexing document failed")
    }
}

fn main() {
    block_on(elastic_search_example());
}
```

Comment: Where are you importing the `block_on` function from?

Comment: It's from `futures::executor::block_on`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It looks like Elasticsearch's crate is using [Tokio](https://crates.io/crates/tokio) internally, so you must use it too to match their assumptions.

Looking for `block_on` function in their documentation, I've got [this](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.2.9/tokio/runtime/struct.Runtime.html#method.block_on). So, it appears that your `main` should look like this:

```
use tokio::runtime::Runtime;

fn main() {
    Runtime::new()
        .expect("Failed to create Tokio runtime")
        .block_on(elastic_search_example());
}
```

Or you can make you `main` function itself async with the [attribute macro](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.2.9/tokio/attr.main.html), which will generate runtime creation and `block_on` call for you:

```
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    elastic_search_example().await;
}
```

Comment: That clarifies a lot. Thank you.

Comment: Using the second approach not compiles, it give these two errors:

error[E0277]: `main` has invalid return type `impl futures::Future`
   --> src\main.rs:110:17
    |
110 | async fn main() {
    |                 ^ `main` can only return types that implement `Termination`
    |
    = help: consider using `()`, or a `Result`

error[E0752]: `main` function is not allowed to be `async`
   --> src\main.rs:110:1
    |
110 | async fn main() {
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `main` function is not allowed to be `async`

Comment: Please ask new question with your real code and real error, since you're either not using the exact same code as in the example or not showing the full error you get.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same error when I used to `tokio::run` (from tokio version = 0.1) with crate that use `tokio02` (tokio version = 0.2) internally (in my case it was reqwest). 
First I just changed `std::future::Future` to `futures01::future::Future` with [`futures03::compat`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.4/futures/future/trait.TryFutureExt.html#method.compat). To make it compile. After run I get exactly your error.

#### Solution:

Adding [tokio-compat](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio-compat) resolved my problem.

---

[More about tokio compat](https://tokio.rs/blog/2019-12-compat/)