# Mixing select! and async calls in Rust

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, rusoto, crossbeam

I am building a small app that's supposed to schedule two tasks (based on `rusoto` AWS SDK) at different intervals: every X seconds, run one task, and every Y seconds, run the other.

I found crate `crossbeam` that offers a tick timer and a `select!` macro and put them all together like this:

```rust
fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {
  let cloudwatch_client = rusoto_cloudwatch::CloudWatchClient::new();
  let rt = Runtime::new().unwrap();
  let tick_a = tick(Duration::from_secs(60));
  let tick_b = tick(Duration::from_secs(30));

  loop {
    select! {
      recv(tick_a) -> _ => {
        rt.block_on(cloudwatch_client.put_metric_data( /* ... */ ));
      },
      /* similar for tick_b */
    }
  }
}
```

This compiles, however the program panics with `thread 'main' panicked at 'not currently running on the Tokio runtime.'`. This seems to come from the Rusoto call, by analyzing the backtrace.

What am I missing here? Is there a way to make this work? Is there a better way to handle the scheduling of tasks at intervals in Rust?

Please note that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59763102/panic-with-thread-main-panicked-at-not-currently-running-on-the-tokio-runtim) question does not seem to address my issue. That question starts out by using `futures::executor::block_on` function and is solved by using the `block_on` method implemented by the tokio `Runtime`. I am already using the `block_on` method in `Runtime`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [panic with "thread 'main' panicked at 'not currently running on the Tokio runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59763102/panic-with-thread-main-panicked-at-not-currently-running-on-the-tokio-runtim)

Comment: @pretzelhammer no, it does not. as you can see, I am already using the first method in the accepted answer of that question (by using the `block_on` function on the tokio Runtime instance). Please note that I have also tried using `#[tokio::main]` and `await` on my CloudWatch call and the result is the same.

Comment: Are you trying to use tokio 0.3? Note that rusoto might still be on 0.2, and the tokio versions are not compatible. If you use the wrong one, you will get this error. You will need to use tokio 0.2 then.

Comment: Note that you can restructure the whole thing to run completely inside a tokio runtime. You can use `tokio::select!` and tokio timers for doing what you do with crossbeam here. That might however not fix your "not currently running on the Tokio runtime" issue.

Comment: @Matthias247 I changed the version of toklo in my project to the one used by rusoto and it fixed the issue. Indeed the two versions were different. Could you please write this and your suggestion for `tokio::select!` in an answer? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> thread 'main' panicked at 'not currently running on the Tokio runtime.'

This error will show up if the version of the tokio runtime that is required by a particular library is not actively running - since each major version uses different thread-local variables and more than 1 major version of a library can be included in the same build.

In your case you might have a Tokio 0.3 runtime running, but rusoto expects a Tokio 0.2 runtime. When rusoto then tries to perform IO via Tokio 0.2 (which is also included in the build), that one detects that no runtime is active and yields the error.

To fix this, make sure to use just a single tokio version in your project. You likely need to downgrade tokio to `0.2` via `Cargo.toml`, since there might be no newer rusoto version available.

**One more unrelated suggestion:**

Instead of using crossbeam for timers, you can also run the "whole thing" inside a tokio runtime: You can use tokio::select! and tokio timers for doing what you do with crossbeam here.

See https://docs.rs/tokio/0.2.24/tokio/time/fn.interval.html
and https://docs.rs/tokio/0.2.24/tokio/macro.select.html (which has examples similar to your use-case)

Answer (score 0):

[`CloudWatchClient::put_metric_data`](https://rusoto.github.io/rusoto/rusoto_cloudwatch/struct.CloudWatchClient.html#method.put_metric_data) returns a [`RusotoFuture`](https://rusoto.github.io/rusoto/rusoto_core/struct.RusotoFuture.html) which has a [`sync`](https://rusoto.github.io/rusoto/rusoto_core/struct.RusotoFuture.html#method.sync) method does what you want. So instead of:

```rust
let cloudwatch_client = rusoto_cloudwatch::CloudWatchClient::new();
let rt = Runtime::new().unwrap();
rt.block_on(cloudwatch_client.put_metric_data(/* ... */));
```

You can do:

```rust
let cloudwatch_client = rusoto_cloudwatch::CloudWatchClient::new();
cloudwatch_client.put_metric_data(/* ... */).sync();
```

[Which is also what the official docs recommend](https://www.rusoto.org/futures.html?highlight=tokio#sync).

Comment: I am using `rusoto_cloudwatch = { version = "0.45.0", default_features = false, features=["rustls"] }` in my Cargo.toml and I am getting: `no method named "sync" found for struct Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = std::result::Result<(), RusotoError<PutMetricDataError>>> + Send>> in the current scope` when trying to use the `sync()` method. I tried that one before asking the question.

Comment: Do you know why that method is missing in the crate I am using?

Answer (score 0):

Please note:

> Note that from v0.43.0 onward, Rusoto uses Rust's std::future::Future, and the Tokio 0.2 ecosystem. From v0.46.0 onward, Rusoto uses the Tokio 1.0 ecosystem.

I'd recommend the following dependencies for a simple S3 call:

```
[dependencies]  
rusoto_core = "0.46.0"                            
rusoto_s3 = "0.46.0"                                                    
tokio = {version = "1.0",  features = ["full"]}
```

The call can be implemented like this:

```
use rusoto_core::Region;
use rusoto_s3::{S3, S3Client};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let region = Region::UsEast1;
    let client = S3Client::new(region);

    match client.list_buckets().await {
        Ok(output) => match output.buckets {
            Some(bucket_list) => {
                println!("Buckets in S3:");

                for bucket in bucket_list {
                    println!("{:?}", bucket.name);
                }
            }
            None => println!("No buckets!"),
        },
        Err(error) => {
            println!("Error: {:?}", error);
        }
    }
}
```

Set credentials to avoid credentials error.